# $a^2=e~\land~a\ast b^2\ast a=b^3\implies b^5=e~~\textrm{for }(G,\ast)~$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm stuck on this seemingly easy problem in elementary group theory.

**Q.** Let $(G,\ast)$ be a group and $a,b\in G$. If $a^2=e$ and $a\ast b^2\ast a=b^3$, prove that $b^5=e$. ($e$ denotes the identity element of $(G,\ast)$)

**Attempt:**

$$a\ast b^2\ast a=b^3\implies a^2\ast b^2\ast a^2=a\ast b^3\ast a\implies a\ast b^3\ast a=b^2\tag1$$

Using $(1)$ and the given two equations in the question, we get,

$$b^5=b^2\ast b^3=a\ast b^3\ast a^2\ast b^2\ast a\implies a\ast b^5\ast a=b^5$$

This is the most progress I think I have done for this problem. I had tried different approaches but they all went in vain.

I'd like hints on this problem rather than a complete solution. Thanks.

Comment: $a*b^4*a=b^6 \Rightarrow b^4=a*b^6*a=b^9$.